# launch a single Edge tab with proxy server

Tags: proxy, microsoft-edge, command-line-arguments

I am using [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/) on windows 11 in standard mode it is listening on localhost:8080. I don't want to reconfigure my system proxy. I just want to reconfigure my proxy for one browser tab (or new window).

[This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-cmdline-options-proxy-settings) says to pass `--proxy-server` to the command line. It doesn't say what the command is. Typing `edge` or `msedge` doesn't start it. So I investiage:

```
PS C:\Users\JustinDearing\source\repos\agents-of-devops> ps msedge| select path, commandline

Path                                                         CommandLine
----                                                         -----------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --type=renderer --display-capture-permissions-policy-allowed --js-flags=--ms-user-locale= --lang=en-US --devic…
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --type=utility --utility-sub-type=audio.mojom.AudioService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=audio --mojo-pl…
. . .
```

But when I run the command:

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --proxy-server="https://localhost:8080" http://www.httpvshttps.com/

The traffic does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has its own mysteries, but I was able to use your command (minus the leading '&') from a 'Command Prompt' and get it to use the proxy.

The tricky thing is that the default behavior of sophisticated apps like Microsoft Edge (or Google Chrome) is to share application instances. As a result, it will ignore your proxy setting unless you are deliberate to close all running instances before launching with your settings (Edge is sneaky -- I would use Task Manager for this).

A possible alternative would be to force a separate instance by specifying a temporary profile or a [user-data-dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-create-user-directory-vars) option. But that's a larger endeavor.